# Why does a re-index operation take over an hour in Algolia?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I'm trying to reindex all records in database of a model by running:

```
ModelName.reindex
```

However, it takes about 8 hours to reindex about 800K records
I searched through [Algolia's](http://www.algolia.com/docs) docs and I couldn't find how long it should take to index a large number of records.

Did anyone face this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in your Algolia dashboard? How many pending jobs re currently being processed? Are the batch of indexing jobs received (you can see them in the logs)?

Comment: @redox: I see a job every ~30 seconds being processed, and it adds 1K entries to the index. I'm using postgres as the database. Could it be this?

Comment: There are many reasons it could be taking that long: they may throttle full reindexes (it shouldn't happen very often anyway), you might have a complicated model and/or indices, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton: What do you mean a complicated model? The model doesn't have any associations or connected tables. It's an app with only one table. I thought maybe moving it into mongodb would help, but I'm not sure.
Also, in model_name.rb, I added the `enqueue: true` option, but I can't see any workers in sidekiq queue related to algolia.

Comment: The model itself may be complicated and require a lot of indexing. Full-text/-property indexing can be slow--you make a tradeoff between indexing and searching costs. I've had ES reindexes that take days, IIRC with fewer records, but there was a lot of text in them.

Comment: If the jobs are coming every 30 sec, it means the whole time is spend either in your rails code (complexity described by @DaveNewton) OR on the network (like the resulting JSON objects are too big and you're uploading them too slowly).